# Error creating virtual disk - The given disk size is not aligned on a sector boundary (512 bytes)

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox, virtualization

When I am trying to create a Virtual Hard Disk for my Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual Machine I am getting this error...

```
Could not create the medium storage unit '/home/mir/VirtualBox VMs/Linux/Ubuntu/Ubuntu.vdi'.

VD: The given disk size 13529146982 is not aligned on a sector boundary (512 bytes) (VERR_VD_INVALID_SIZE).

Result Code: 
VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: 
MediumWrap
Interface: 
IMedium {4afe423b-43e0-e9d0-82e8-ceb307940dda}
```

[image: img_VirtualBox_Error]

I am giving 12.60 GB of space for the virtual Hard Disk as you can see in the image below

[image: img_Disk_size]

What is the problem? It is not a disk space problem for sure, because once I installed it in 10 GB of space and it was working completely fine.

Comment: How much free space has your host system?

Comment: Currently, I have 200 GB of free space

Comment: It should be mentioned that your question has been closed on stack overflow. You should be more precise about your system.  Add your host system to the question

Comment: Yes, they closed it. My issue is very similar to this one.  https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=90724

Comment: It has been fixed 3 years ago. I'm pretty sure that the error is on your side. But since you don't answer questions, we can't help - Host System? How did you install your VirtualBox (Repo or Oracle)?

Comment: Repo.  Version 5.2

Comment: Ok, current Version is 6.1

Comment: Host - Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: So host and guest are the same? (Host is, where VirtualBox has been installed, guest is what you install **in** VB)

Comment: Yes both are same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

12.60 GB is 13,529,146,982 bytes, so it is not a multiple of 512 bytes

Disk capacity must be a multiple of 512 bytes
You can use a capacity that is a multiple of 512 bytes, such as 12GB or 12.5GB
The reason is that 512 bytes of a hard disk are 1 sector, so the number of sectors must be a natural number

Answer (score 0):

When setting up my virtual machines (currently > 12 running) I always follow these steps:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

[image: 6]

Comment: OK, Give it 12.60 GB of space, instead of 12.00 GB. Probably, you may also face the same issue

Comment: Tried with 12 GB? This was just an example. It works with any number. Just for fun: try it with 12GB. If it works I'll shave my head ;-). Btw Fixed size I've never tried. OK, tried. Created 12.60 GB - no problem